# Test behavior of assembled jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I would like to write an Integration Test which test if the created jar behaves like expected. For that I have to know the path to the jar as well the name, but how to I get this Information. I do not like the idea of hard coding this. Is there a way to get the Information from maven? Or what is the best practice for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembled jar is placed inside directory which is accessible from [maven properties](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide)

```
${project.build.directory}
```

Jar name is configured in [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) or [assembly descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html). For simplicity define property `project.build.finalName` in your `pom.xml`.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.finalName>my-artifact.jar</project.build.finalName>
</properties>
```

After this your jar is accessible with variable:

```
${project.build.directory}/my-artifact.jar
```

Simply [filter this value with maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) into application properties and voila :)

Is this helping you in any way?